# How can I get the caller from Bloodhound

Tags: javascript, parameters, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using typeahead with Bloodhound and I need to get the caller element id from Bloodhound.
This is the code:

```
    var destinations = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: '/json/cities/1',
        remote: {
            url: "/json/cities/%COUNTRY/%QUERY",
            replace: function (url, uriEncodedQuery) {                    
                return url.replace('%QUERY', uriEncodedQuery).replace('%COUNTRY', $('#country_1').val());
            },                
        },
        limit: 30
    });
    destinations.initialize();
```

as you can see, just for example, I replace %COUNTRY with `$('#country_1').val()` but I need the caller id, getting the index and than get the correct country_id. `$('#country_+caller.getPartOfId()).val()`

is this possibile?

Comment: what do you mean by caller id ? The element that has the typeahead ?

Comment: yes, because there are more than one typeahead in the page and they all use the same bloodhound source.